# How to get value of one of <td> from several <td> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have got the next code:

```
<tr>
    <td id='type'> Type name </td>
    <td id='number'> 102030 </td>
    <td id='software'> 1.0-Alpha </td>
</tr>
```

I need to get value of td with id 'number'.
I use the next code right now and it works:

```
$('tbody tr').click(function() {
    var tdNumber = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
});
```

But I don't want to find by child element, but by id. How can I do that?

Comment: if it is id, use $("#number").text()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have multiple rows like this if so

```
<tr>
    <td class='type'> Type name </td>
    <td class='number'> 102030 </td>
    <td class='software'> 1.0-Alpha </td>
</tr>

$('tbody tr').click(function() {
    var tdNumber = $(this).find('.number').html();
})
```

Otherwise(ie you have only one element with the given id) then you can use the id-selector as ID of an element must be unique

```
var tdNumber = $('#number').html();
```

Comment: kindly change this line like : $(this).find('#number').html();

Comment: Thank you Arun, you are also right, but jQueryKing was first.

Comment: @JEYCDEE no... you should not use that as ID of an element must be unique... you should change your code to use a class or some other selector...

Answer (score 2):

To target ids, simply use `#`

```
$('#number').html();
```

This will search the whole `document` for an element with `id="number"`

Answer (score 1):

**you missed out closing brace in your code**.

```
    $('tbody tr').click(function() {
        var tdNumber = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
    });
//---^
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. It is simple. The thing is I tried to change nth element to an td's id and it didn't work for me. Now I see where was my mistake.

Comment: @JqueryKing please dont point OP to a wrong direction., Id should be unique.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - Yes id be unique what wrong with my code

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - Actually he missed the closing braces i point out that only not the id